# Site apontando que perguntas são duplicadas sem serem?

Tags: suporte

Fiz uma pergunta: [O que é um algoritmo Backtracking?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103184/o-que-%C3%A9-um-algoritmo-backtracking) esta pergunta foi bem aceita e inserida no site corretamente, porém dois dias depois tentei inserir uma segunda pergunta: [O que é um Algoritmo Guloso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103681/o-que-%C3%A9-um-algoritmo-guloso) e ela foi barrada pelo próprio site exibido uma mensagem afirmando que a segunda era duplicata da primeira, para contornar isto tive de quebrar a formatação e inserir outro conteúdo pergunta para que pude-se publica-la (editei assim que a pergunta foi publicada).

O que posso fazer quando isto acontecer novamente ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta é uma trava do sistema para evitar *spam* de usuários mal-intencionados ou que inadvertidamente inserem a mesma pergunta várias vezes ou com pequenas variações.

Você foi "pego" no filtro porque suas perguntas são idênticas, exceto algumas palavras.

Minha sugestão é: se for inserir mais perguntas/respostas sobre algoritmos ou temas parecidos, tente não ficar usando o mesmo modelo com o mesmo texto. Faça com que a pergunta seja mais natural e menos com cara de catálogo.